# NumPy: how to left join arrays with duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, cython

To use Cython, I need to convert `df1.merge(df2, how='left')` (using `Pandas`) to plain `NumPy`, while I found `numpy.lib.recfunctions.join_by(key, r1, r2, jointype='leftouter')` doesn't support any duplicates along `key`. Is there any way to solve it?

Comment: The basic idea in most `recfunctions` is to define a new dtype, create the appropriate 'empty' array, and copy values by field name.   It's all readable python; no hidden compiled code.  If existing functions don't do the job (they aren't heavily used or tested), write your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a stab at a pure `numpy` left join that can handle duplicate keys:

```
import numpy as np

def join_by_left(key, r1, r2, mask=True):
    # figure out the dtype of the result array
    descr1 = r1.dtype.descr
    descr2 = [d for d in r2.dtype.descr if d[0] not in r1.dtype.names]
    descrm = descr1 + descr2 

    # figure out the fields we'll need from each array
    f1 = [d[0] for d in descr1]
    f2 = [d[0] for d in descr2]

    # cache the number of columns in f1
    ncol1 = len(f1)

    # get a dict of the rows of r2 grouped by key
    rows2 = {}
    for row2 in r2:
        rows2.setdefault(row2[key], []).append(row2)

    # figure out how many rows will be in the result
    nrowm = 0
    for k1 in r1[key]:
        if k1 in rows2:
            nrowm += len(rows2[k1])
        else:
            nrowm += 1

    # allocate the return array
    _ret = np.recarray(nrowm, dtype=descrm)
    if mask:
        ret = np.ma.array(_ret, mask=True)
    else:
        ret = _ret

    # merge the data into the return array
    i = 0
    for row1 in r1:
        if row1[key] in rows2:
            for row2 in rows2[row1[key]]:
                ret[i] = tuple(row1[f1]) + tuple(row2[f2])
                i += 1
        else:
            for j in range(ncol1):
                ret[i][j] = row1[j]
            i += 1

    return ret
```

Basically, it uses a plain `dict` to do the actual join operation. Like `numpy.lib.recfunctions.join_by`, this func will also return a masked array. When  there are keys missing from the right array, those values will be masked out in the return array. If you would prefer a record array instead (in which all of the missing data is set to 0), you can just pass `mask=False` when calling `join_by_left`.