# How to join numpy structured array with duplicates

Tags: python, numpy, join, structured-array

R user here, and I'm attempting my first project in Python to take advantage of Numba. I've read that Numba works very well with Numpy but not well with Pandas, so I am attempting to avoid Pandas. My current question actually has nothing to do with Numba, but I wanted to mention it as my reason for avoiding Pandas.

I have two Numpy structured arrays, one with many duplicates. I am attempting to join them using the "numpy.lib.recfunctions.join_by" function, but the documentation explicitly states that duplicates cause problems. Can anybody recommend any workarounds for all my duplicates?

Here is an example similar to my situation:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.lib.recfunctions as rfn

a = np.zeros(4, dtype={'names':('name', 'age'),
                       'formats':('U10','f8')})
a['name'] = ['Alex', 'Billy', 'Charlie', 'Dave']
a['age'] = [25, 25, 75, 75]

b = np.zeros(2, dtype={'names':('age', 'senior'),
                       'formats':('f8', 'i4')})
b['age'] = [25, 75]
b['senior'] = [0, 1]

c = rfn.join_by('age', a, b, jointype='leftouter', usemask=False)

print(c)
[(25., 'Alex',      0) (75., 'Billy',      1) (75., 'Charlie', 999999)
(75., 'Dave', 999999)]
```

This (1) changes the "age" of Billy from 25 to 75 and (2) gives a "senior" value of 999999 for Charlie & Dave.

Does anybody have a workaround for the duplicates restriction of this function? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This looks like a job for pandas, not numpy.

Comment: Both Pandas and Numpy uses fast compiled code underneath. You can really use Pandas because of this, numba will not provide a significant speedup above Pandas. But then again to measure is to know.

Comment: I hear that this is easier with Pandas, but like I mentioned, I'd really like to find a workaround in Numpy to take advantage of Numba (which supposedly doesn't work well with Pandas)

Comment: Does my below answer help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53257916/numpy-how-to-left-join-arrays-with-duplicates . In any case, the answer there can be modified slightly to answer this.

Answer (score 0):

Why instead of joining not do a comparison? This works much better in your example.

I realize this wont work for arbitrary joins where you have a set of keys that have to map to values. There I recommend you loop over the keys and build up the array from scratch starting with an empty array filled with NaNs, and using [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to find and replace the values in the array.

Using this starting code:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.lib.recfunctions as rfn

a = np.zeros(4, dtype={'names':('name', 'age'),
                       'formats':('U10','f8')})
a['name'] = ['Alex', 'Billy', 'Charlie', 'Dave']
a['age'] = [25, 25, 75, 75]
```

you can do:

```
d = rfn.append_fields(a, names='senior', data=(a['age'] >= 65).astype(int))
print(d)
```

which results in:

```
[('Alex', 25.0, 0) ('Billy', 25.0, 0) ('Charlie', 75.0, 1) ('Dave', 75.0, 1)]
```

The main reason for using Numba is to speed up python code. Numpy and Pandas already have these speedups below the hood.

Answer (score 0):

Under the cover the recfunctions usually construct a new dtype, and 'blank' result array.  Then they copy values by field name.  I haven't studied the `join_by`, but I can imagine your join being like this:

```
In [11]: a.dtype                                                                          
Out[11]: dtype([('name', '<U10'), ('age', '<f8')])
In [12]: b.dtype                                                                          
Out[12]: dtype([('age', '<f8'), ('senior', '<i4')])
In [13]: b.dtype[1]                                                                       
Out[13]: dtype('int32')
In [14]: b.dtype.descr                                                                    
Out[14]: [('age', '<f8'), ('senior', '<i4')]

In [16]: dt = np.dtype(a.dtype.descr+[b.dtype.descr[1]])                                  
In [17]: dt                                                                               
Out[17]: dtype([('name', '<U10'), ('age', '<f8'), ('senior', '<i4')])

In [18]: e = np.zeros(a.shape, dt)                                                        
In [19]: for name in a.dtype.names: 
    ...:     e[name] = a[name] 
    ...:                                                                                  

In [21]: e                                                                                
Out[21]: 
array([('Alex', 25., 0), ('Billy', 25., 0), ('Charlie', 75., 0),
       ('Dave', 75., 0)],
      dtype=[('name', '<U10'), ('age', '<f8'), ('senior', '<i4')])
```

With a bit trial and error I found this way of pairing the `b` ages with the `a` (now `e`) ones:

```
In [23]: e['age'][:,None]==b['age']                                                       
Out[23]: 
array([[ True, False],
       [ True, False],
       [False,  True],
       [False,  True]])
In [25]: np.where(Out[23])                                                                
Out[25]: (array([0, 1, 2, 3]), array([0, 0, 1, 1]))
```

Now just copy the corresponding 'senior' values from `b` to `e`:

```
In [27]: e['senior'][Out[25][0]] = b['senior'][Out[25][1]]                                
In [28]: e                                                                                
Out[28]: 
array([('Alex', 25., 0), ('Billy', 25., 0), ('Charlie', 75., 1),
       ('Dave', 75., 1)],
      dtype=[('name', '<U10'), ('age', '<f8'), ('senior', '<i4')])
```

The underlying logic does not depend on these being structured arrays.  We just as well have individual 1d arrays of `names`, `ages`, `senior_category_age`, etc.

The `recfunctions` don't get a lot of use - as evident from the separate packaging, and from limited SO questions.  However recent changes in multifield indexing will, I think, increase it use, at least for the newly added functions.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html#accessing-multiple-fields